# Scrapy CrawlSpider Post-processing: Finding an Average

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Let's say I have a crawl spider similar to this example:
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from scrapy.item import Item

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = Item()
        item['id'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Let's say I wanted to get some information like the sum of the IDs from each of the pages, or the average number of characters in the description across all of the parsed pages.  How would I do it?

Also, how could I get averages for a particular category?

Comment: For some reason I can't get the import statements in the code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Scrapy's [stats collector](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/stats.html) to build this kind of information or gather the necessary data to do so as you go. For per-category stats, you could use a per-category stats key.

For a quick dump of all stats gathered during a crawl, you can add `STATS_DUMP = True` to your `settings.py`.

[Redis](http://redis.io) (via [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)) is also a great option for stats collection.

Comment: How could I print the stats to a file?

Comment: Actually what I would really like is some way to write arbitrary code that interacts with the finalized stats.